# how to enable desktop effects in the window without java decoration

Tags: java, linux

When I create a jframe with decoration all the window effects are shown, but if I remove the decoration the window no longer shows anything and I would like to implement the wobbly window effect that kde plasma has, any ideas on how to do it? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2tx8.jpg)

Sorry for the English, I'm translating with Google Translator.

Comment: The decorations of the frame are implemented by the frame of the underlying OS (not Swing). If you remove the decorations you lose the OS custom functionality.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.